# Multiple annotations found at this line: - The markup in the document following the root element must be well- formed

Tags: android, xml, parsing, r.java-file

I'm new to coding and want to learn really bad.
I am on the developer.android.com site to teach myself.
Unfortunately, I have run into a quagmire and can't get past this code.
Please, help. What am I doing wrong?
If you want to look at the exercise here is the address:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html#Button

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding ="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />

    <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message" />
     <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/button_send" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is here:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

Note that you have

```
/>
```

This closes the linear layout tag.  It should look like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android ="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

without the closing /
```

Note:

If you are on linux, a REALLY easy way to determine if you've copied code from tutorials correctly is using Meld. I copied your code into a file name 1, the tutorial code in a file named 2 and did "meld 1 2", the resultant UI displayed exactly what your error was without my even having to think

Edit:

First - meld for windows;

http://meldmerge.org/

For your issue with the param:

```
@String/edit_message
```

You need to define this value in the string resources of your application.  The following is taken from

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html

```
FILE LOCATION:
res/values/filename.xml  // in oyur case this will likely be Strings.xml

The filename is arbitrary. The <string> element's name will be used as the resource ID.

COMPILED RESOURCE DATATYPE:
Resource pointer to a String.

RESOURCE REFERENCE:
In Java: R.string.string_name
In XML:@string/string_name

SYNTAX:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string
        name="string_name"  // in your case this will be name="edit_message"
        >text_string</string>
</resources>
```

If the file doesn't exist, you can create it in the location:

```
/res/values/strings.xml
```

Define your values and such there and everything should be fixed.

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I am not working with linux. I have windows.I am still having a issue with this part:   <EditText android:id="@+id/edit_message"
     android:layout_weight="1"
     android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:hint="@string/edit_message"
 </EditText>

Comment: What's your actual issue?

Comment: Have you defined the @String param that you're referencing?  Otherwise your code in your question is correct.

Comment: I keep getting "Multiple annotations found at this line:
 - error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'hint' with value '@string/
  edit_message')." with this particular block of code.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! I had to build the resources just as you said.